# PHP SimpleXML produce some unknown encoding

Tags: php, simplexml

When I execute the code below,

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT xxx");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  $str = $row[0];
  echo $str;
}
```

I got the message below if I check the sources(Chinese words, UTF-8 encoding as below),

```
LS23A300BS（23”LED顯示器）/ LS22A300BS（21.5”LED顯示器）
```

But, when I added the code to convert the SQL result to XML file as below,

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "items" ));
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT xxx");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  $item = $sxe->addChild("item");
  $str = $row[0];  
  $item->addChild("desc", $str);
}

echo $sxe->asXML();

mysql_free_result($result);
```

I got the message below if I check the sources (unknown encoding as below),

```
LS23A300BS&#xFF08;23&#x201D;LED&#x986F;&#x793A;&#x5668;&#xFF09;/ LS22A300BS&#xFF08;21.5&#x201D;LED&#x986F;&#x793A;&#x5668;&#xFF09;
```

I want to ask, 
What is the type of the unknown encoding?
How can I change this unknown encoding back to UTF-8?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

1. Use `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');` instead of `character_set_results`. This sets a few more key MySQL settings to utf8.
2. You don't declare the encoding of your DOMDocument. Try using this as your constructor: `new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8')`

This is an aside: You don't need `DOMDocument` at all here. Try `$sxe = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><items/>');`

Comment: +1 Thanks, solved the problem by changing `new domDocument` to `new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8')`.